# Pointer to member using _asm

Tags: c, assembly

I've been trying to go from a line of code in c to assembly, but I just can't figure out what would be the correct translation of the pointer-to-member function using asm.
Here is a fragment of the code:

```
struct file{
int size;
}FILE;

void function(FILE *result){
result -> size;
}
```

Comment: "Using asm" is not informative enough to answer this question - which architecture?

Comment: `result->size` is of course `(*result).size`, which given that `size` is the first member is just `*result` and that's a simple dereferencing in whatever architecture you use.

Comment: @Govind Parmar I'm using x86

Comment: Look at compiler output (e.g. on http://gcc.godbolt.org/) for a function like `int foo(FILE *p) { return p->size; }` to find the right offset (and syntax).  Also, unless you're implementing stdio, don't use `FILE` as a type name.

Comment: Somebody should probably mention that using inline asm is usually a [bad idea](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm).  Unless this is a class project that has this as a requirement or a "learning experience."  Usually when people try to use inline asm, they want to speed up their code.  Often what they end up with is code that is slower, doesn't always work right, or is difficult to troubleshoot/maintain (sometimes all 3).  That said, there are ways to find out the 'offsetof' data members.  How to combine that with inline asm depends on what compiler you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a x86-64 compiler,

`_function:
    ; rdi = pointer to struct file
    ; rax = size element
    mov eax, [rdi]`